# Unexpected token error while using if

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have a property called name, which depends on an index, part of delegates of a list view. I had written this code :

```
 property string name : if ( index == 0 )
                        "ABC"
                        else if ( index == 1 )
                         "DEF"
                        else if ( index == 2 )
                         "GHI"
                        else if ( index == 3 )
                         "JKL"
                        else if ( index == 4 )
                         "MNO"
                        else 
                         "XYZ"
```

It works perfectly fine on Qt5(Linux), but when I ran it on Qt4.7(Windows), I started getting a weird error :

> Unexpected token `if' 
>                        property string name : if ( index == 0 )
>
> Expected a qualified name id 
>                                                   "ABC"

Can someone give an idea what might be wrong ?

Comment: Just a guess: Qt5 = qtquick 2. Qt4 = qtquick 1. Maybe you used qtquick 2 features, which don't work in qtquick 1?

Comment: I'd say that on Qt4.7 you couldn't define a `property` with multiple `if/else`. Did you try calling a function instead?

Comment: @Greenflow This doesnt look like a new 'feature' to me as such. I have already made the necessary changes otherwise (changing the import statement to QtQuick 1.0).

Comment: @koopajah Functions work fine, I have been using them. I also guessed the same what you are suggesting, but can't find a documentation for the same. Any clues about the proper documentation regarding this ?

Comment: @AmitTomar > I found only this: http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qdeclarativeintroduction.html#attached-properties which shows example of how to use properties and none of these are using if/else.

Comment: @koopajah Well, they have just 'if,else' kind of requirements, so the ternary operator is good enough :-). I have to use 'if,elseif,elseif..' coz there are too many conditions to check. Anyways, I changed the code to use function as of now, lets see if someone else comes up with a better solution. Thanks..

Comment: @AmitTomar > Why don't you use Qt5.1 on Windows as on Linux ?

Comment: @koopajah It works fine on Windows with Qt5, but there is another problem if I use Qt5 on Windows. Where ever I have text, I see colored dots all around. Will be posting that as a separate question.

Comment: @koopajah This is what I was talking about : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533343/colored-dots-on-using-text-element-in-qt5

Comment: And why a down vote now !?

Answer (score 0):

It works, albeit you may need to wrap the if/else if/else if/.../else into `{}`.

Comment: You tried { if .... else ... } or if () {} else {}, or both? It works here... Although using Qt 4.8.5

Comment: I tried all the possible combinations. {if{} else{}}, {if else},if{}else{} etc.. But neither works.. I am using Qt 4.7 though..

Comment: "neither works" does not work. Please show the command line error message. Also, have you tried with 4.8? Have you tried this with Qt 4.7 on Linux? It works here fine, so I am now curious.

Comment: @AmitTomar: is it still unresolved more than one year later??